# Set-WebConfigurationProperty fails

Tags: wcf, iis, powershell

I am trying to use powershell to set windowsauth on a site in IIS, this part of the script has worked in all environments so far and has now failed and I cannot figure out why.

```
Set-WebConfigurationproperty system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name enabled -value false -PSPath "IIS:\" -location $siteName
Set-WebConfigurationproperty system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication -name enabled -value true -PSPath "IIS:\" -location $siteName
```

Anyone got any ideas as to why this script would fail?

I get a "The configuration section 'system.serviceModel' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration"

I can manually enable windows auth and the site spins up just fine.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was not having .Net 3.5 installed.

As powershell runs under .Net2 CLR without having 3.5 installed it didn't know what system.serviceModel was in the web.config.

Once 3.5 was installed the script ran fine

Comment: forgot to tell you to install 3.5 SP1... ! Good job!

Answer (score 1):

1) Verify the .NET framework 3.0 (or higher) is installed.

2) Execute the following command as administrator:

"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -i

Hope can help

Comment: I dont have .Net 3 installed, but found the same .exe in the 4.0 directory. That command requires you to specify packages to install so I used -ia which is all packages. Unfortunately this produces the same error :(